# How can I create a multi-line splash screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a basic splashscreen for a website but for some reason only 1 line of text is showing up on the splashscreen, and not the remaining text within the `<p>` tag. Here is a codepen of the problem:
[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/jerguy1928/pen/QWyjWMX) of the problem.

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.splash {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90vh;
}

.splash.display-none {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <div class="splash">
    <p class="fade-in">Hi there! This splashscreen is broken!<br> I can't see this line!<br> I can't see this line either!<br> This line is also missing too!</p>
  </div>

  <p>hello world</p>
```

I'm sure it's a relatively simple fix, just a bit stumped on this one.

Comment: hint: `line-height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **because of the huge amount of [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)** that you have given to your `<p>` tag so each line will occupy `90vh` **so it will be out of the screen**. **If you want your text to have appeared in the middle of the element with class `splash` you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** to achieve this instead of `line-height`.

All you have to do is to set the element with `splash` class `display: flex;` and then with `justify-content` and  `align-items` attribute position it to center horizontally and vertically.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.splash {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.splash.display-none {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <p class="fade-in">Hi there! This splashscreen is broken!<br> I can't see this line!<br> I can't see this line either!<br> This line is also missing too!</p>
</div>

<p>hello world</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using this splashscreen before loading an interactive map. It seems I can't interact with the map after the splashscreen has faded away. Is there something I could do so I can then interact with the page afterwards?

Comment: @JeremyHerbert Your welcome, actually this is another problem that you are facing right now and according to [SO guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments), this is not appropriate to extend your question in comments. So you need to ask another follow-up question with posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line for `line-height: 90vh;` in your `.splash` css